# Custom validator in Laravel 5 fails

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm trying to use a custom validator of laravel 5, I intend to validate two fields so that one is greater than the other. Follow the steps in this link http://goo.gl/3236xn but could not make the application call the validation method. Can anyone give any tips?

Step 1: Make a bind class where you can implement each rule you want extending Validator class, as follow:

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use \Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class GreaterThanValidator extends Validator
{
    public function validateGreaterThan($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if (isset($parameters[1])) {
           $other = $parameters[1];
           return (floatval($value) > floatval($other)) ;
        } else {
          return true;
       }
    }
}
```

Step 2:Make a service provider that extends ServiceProvider, as follow:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\GreaterThanValidator;

class ValidatorsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Log::info('passando pelo provider...');

        \Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
             Log::info('chamando new...');
             return new \App\Services\GreaterThanValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
         });
    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Step 3:Add your custom validator provider at config/app.php file.

```
        /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ValidatorsServiceProvider',
```

I forgot to specify, but the controller have the following rule

```
$rules = array(
            'vlFixado' => 'greater_than:vl_anulacao,' . $vlAnulacao,
    );
```

To validate:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: Can you plz show where you call it in the application?

Comment: The controller have the following rules:$rules = array(
    'vlFixado' => 'greater_than:vl_anulacao,' .$vlAnulacao);

Comment: What does it do? What does it say? It should at least say "can't find validator" or something...

Comment: @Rudie the field vlFixado must be greater than the vlAnulacao field. The Validator should make this check, returning false if vlFixado is less than the vlAnulação.

No exception is thrown.

Comment: @mopo922 the validation is performed by the controller of the next code line: $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);